# CSS Transitioning HTML List Elements

Tags: html-lists, css-transitions

Is it possible to transition HTML list elements, `li`, one at a time using CSS? I'm creating IDs for each list element, but I'm not sure if there's an easier, more efficient way to do this.

If I use the CSS child selector

```
ul > li {
font-size:12pt
transition:all .4s ease 1s;
}
.class:hover ul {
font-size:12pt
}
```

Won't it apply the same timings to each `li` element? That's what I'm most concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to create IDs for eacg **li** elements, you can use 
*ul > :first-child*, *ul > :last-child*, *ul > :nthchild* for accessing any elements inside